# Mod x Page not updating

Tags: modx

I've created a snippet and included it on my template and when I make changes to the file it does not show. If I view the snippet it looks like it has changed

This is my snippet (really simple):

```
echo date();
```

This is my update:

```
echo rand(0, 1000);
```

Shown above is the change however in my template it will not change.

I know this might seems stupid (it is). However I hope you can help.

Comment: Is your snippet linked to a file on your server or is it dynamically saved in the database?

Comment: I pasted it into the wysiwyg in the back end on my browser if that makes sense

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? `Site`->`Clear Cache`

Comment: It worked. \o/ Many thanks. I feel like an idiot, but hey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If partial cache is enabled then you will find you will have to clear the Modx cache manually.

To do this, log into the admin area, and go to:

`Site` -> `Clear Cache`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem again, then I realised the template wasn't linked to a static file.

So if this happens to you, check your template.